# How to create a Table in SQL Server Express - Microsoft

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, windows

so I'm still a student, playing around with C#.

as my first Test, I made a login Form in C#

but now, I have to make a Database to store passwords/usernames (No need encryption for now, im just having fun, nothing very serious)

I have Installed SQL Server Expression from Microsoft aswell as the SSMS coming with it to manage the SQL Server.

How do I create a Table, and then ; how do i connect my data base to my DataBase?

Comment: https://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/Using-SQL-Server-Management-Studio-Table-Designer-to-create-a-table           ------follow this link to create table

Comment: IF you serch for that in google than easily find this how to create database and table in Sql Express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a statement SQL

```
CREATE TABLE
(
    Field1 varchar(50),
    Field2 varchar(50),
    Field3 int
)
```

A little documentation
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp

Or simply you can use MS Management Studio

[image: Create table menu]

Table Designer...

[image: Create table designer]

Answer (score 0):

This is how you create table :

```
CREATE TABLE employees
(
    employee_id INT NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(50),
    salary MONEY
);
```

Comment: check this out for creating database: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AK_mKHWpZBw